# Adding Class To UL using Nav Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am making a navigation bar and want to add a class to the main `UL`tag of the menu, does any one know how can i add class to to this element. Currently `options` and `linkOptions` are available which apply the attributes to the link / anchor and the parent `LI`of the anchor.

Here is my current code.

```
NavBar::begin([
        'innerContainerOptions'=>['class'=>'container-fluid'],
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'style-ihozflem','style'=>'left: 125px; width: 730px; position: absolute; top: 20px; height: 24px;','data'=>['state'=>'center notMobile', 'dropmode'=>"dropDown"]
        ],

    ]);
    echo Nav::widget([
        'encodeLabels'=>false,
        'activateItems'=>true,
        'items' => $menuItems,
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add options class to Nav::widget

```
echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'whatever-class navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'encodeLabels'=>false,
    'activateItems'=>true,
    'items' => $menuItems,
]);
```

Hope that will be helpful!

Comment: hmm you are right about using options, and it adds the class to the `UL` tag but it still appends the default `nav` class on the `UL`, any idea how to do that

Comment: you can't remove the default `nav` class because the purpose of the Nav widget is to render bootstrap nav which uses this class. so if you want to render only ul with links you have to do it yourself using `Html::ul`, see this lists example: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html#lists

Comment: yeah i have to override he css properties for nav class rather than removing it .